# Access violation at address 5000CC82 in module 'rtl120.bpl'. Write of address 2067B5D4

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I installed Delphi 2009 in Windows 7/x64
When I tried to run Delphi, this crashes at startup with the error message:

Access violation at address 5000CC82 in module 'rtl120.bpl'. Write of address 2067B5D4

I tried to reinstall, but didn't help.

Any suggestions to how to solve this thing?

Comment: Mybe your rtl120.bpl is gone, because of some "Tuning" tools? Have you tried to run Delphi in adminmode?

Comment: Is it crashing on the first run? If so, open a free help ticket at Embarcadero for the installation problem.

Comment: @fisi-pjm: If the BPL is missing, how could there be an error **in module 'rtl120.bpl'**? The error would be that the BPL couldn't be found.